# How to implement iAds in Xcode 3.2.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iad

I am new to iPhone SDK. My project is working with Xcode 3.2.4 in simulator 4.1 successfully worked with iAds concept but same project installed Xcode 3.2.5 in simulator 4.2 project working Successfully But iAds are not came. In console also they no errors. When ever change the Xcode version any changes is compulsorily please tell me what is the problem.

My error is Xcode 3.2.4 iAds working but Xcode 3.2.5 iAds not working.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to run any application of previous version of xcode in new version then click on project tab and select edit project settings. You get new window in which u change the base sdk type and select latest know ios. After that you again click on project tab then click on edit target settings and again change base sdk settings and set as latest known ios. After that in editor windoe change base sdk simulator.
It will work .

if u don't get any solution from this then use this link[same question and see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508477/i-am-using-xcode-3-2-5-i-have-iads-running-confused-about-about-targest-ios-ve)